# How open Monero wallet and sweep_all with one command in CLI?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, sweep-transaction

I want run only one string in command line. 
And that after executing this command, the wallet opens, syncs, and funds are sent.

Answer (score 1):

```
monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file MyWallet --password MyPass sweep_all address
```

Comment: In this case, it does not work if the wallet does not have an unlocked balance. It need to sync it first, and then your command will work. Without sync your command not work. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/bb73yGM

Comment: Well obviously I assumed your wallet had some existing balance. If you need to sync as well, just chain two commands. `monero-wallet-cli ... refresh; monero-wallet-cli ... sweep_all ...`